Custom disabling ScrollView scrolling when used with recyclerlistview
I have the following React Native code.
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import {
  DataProvider,
  LayoutProvider,
  RecyclerListView,
} from "recyclerlistview";

const MyComponent = () => {
  // define DataProvider & LayoutProvider here

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      // some content

      <RecyclerListView
        // props
      />
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

As you can see, the recyclerlistview is nested inside the ScrollView, with starting position like below.

When I keep scrolling, at about 50px of the ScrollView remaining on top, it becomes disabled. The recyclerlistview itself is still scrollable.

This behaviour seems specific to recyclerlistview, as replacing it with a FlatList or another ScrollView will not disable the scroll of the parent ScrollView.
It seems to always disable scroll with 50px of ScrollView left on top, no matter what padding/margin/content I add before the recyclerlistview.
My question is, is it possible to specify the height to something other than 50px?
Thanks

I think it would be better to understand your question if you said it got stuck instead of it becomes disabled. Because nothing got disabled, the inner scroller got stuck at the 50px remained to reach the very top of the screen. Anyway, can you share a Snack Expo or some more code to share to help you?

Also, I've got another question, Why did you wrap the RecyclerListView by a ScrollView? I built a Snack Expo sample for you. I brought an example from the GitHub of the RecyclerListView library. It works like a charm. I think you should share more codes of you. It works on my end. What are the props of the RecyclerListView component in your implementation?

You can adjust the scroll/height dynamically via onScroll and onMomentumScrollEnd. In the below example handle scroll is used for setting the contentOffset.y enable/disable on the value of scroll offset value less or greater than 50.
Refer the code below for reference:


import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  DataProvider,
  LayoutProvider,
  RecyclerListView,
} from "recyclerlistview";

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const MyComponent = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollEnabled, setScrollEnabled] = React.useState(true);

  const dataProvider = new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2).cloneWithRows([
    // some other code comes here...
  ]);

  const layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider(
    index => 0,
    (type, dim) => {
      dim.width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
      dim.height = 100; // Set height as needed
    }
  );

  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    if (offsetY >= 50) {
      setScrollEnabled(false);
    } else {
      setScrollEnabled(true);
    }
  };

  const handleMomentumScrollEnd = (event) => {
    const offsetY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    if (offsetY < 50) {
      setScrollEnabled(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
      onMomentumScrollEnd={handleMomentumScrollEnd}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
    >
      {/* your-data-here */}
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>Some content before RecyclerListView</Text>
      </View>
      <RecyclerListView
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        rowRenderer={(type, data) => (
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>{data}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  content: {
    height: height / 3, // Change this value as per your need
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  item: {
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default MyComponent;



